# How to decode bit code to emoji python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, decode, emoji

How to decode bit code to emoji from each text of a row in pandas, study case sentiment analysis

| Text | Sentimen |
| --- | --- |
| \xf0\x9f\x8e\xb6 la la la...hm hmm \xf0\x9f\x8e\xa7 "Semua diam ,semua bisu"\n"Kita coba tanya sama rumput yg bergoyang" \xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xaa\xe2\x99\xaa\xe2\x99\xaa' | Positif |
| Cerita silat lae \xf0\x9f\x98\x80 semacam wejangan | Negatif |
| sewot..\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82 dukung dia terus | Positif |
| kunyuk!!!!\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82 kuy gaslah | Negatif |
| aku sudah mengalaminya \xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82 tetiba muncul grub wa | Negatif |
| g\n\nlagi bosan huft \xf0\x9f\x98\xaa | Negatif |

How I want it to look:

| Text | Sentimen |
| --- | --- |
| la la la...hm hmm "Semua diam ,semua bisu"\n"Kita coba tanya sama rumput yg bergoyang" ♫♫♫♪♪♪'' | Positif |
| Cerita silat lae semacam wejangan | Negatif |
| sewot... dukung dia terus | Positif |
| kunyuk!!!! kuy gaslah | Negatif |
| aku sudah mengalaminya tetiba muncul grub wa | Negatif |
| lagi bosan huft | Negatif |

I've tried it but make contents comments from text fields all become NaN
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCwEQ.png)

I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: i'm sorry sir. my first code just like this => 
b'\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xaa\xe2\x99\xaa\xe2\x99\xaa'.decode()

I have difficulty including the entire text which contains the bit code

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a [mcve]. How did you get the table in question?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `encoding` parameter while converting source to a data frame.

**Example** with hard-coded text:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data_string='''
Text    Sentimen
\xf0\x9f\x8e\xb6 la la la...hm hmm \xf0\x9f\x8e\xa7 "Semua diam ,semua bisu" "Kita coba tanya sama rumput yg bergoyang" \xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xaa\xe2\x99\xaa\xe2\x99\xaa'   Positif
Cerita silat lae \xf0\x9f\x98\x80 semacam wejangan  Negatif
sewot..\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82 dukung dia terus    Positif
kunyuk!!!!\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82 kuy gaslah   Negatif
aku sudah mengalaminya \xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x82 tetiba muncul grub wa   Negatif
g lagi bosan huft \xf0\x9f\x98\xaa  Negatif
'''.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')

df = pd.read_csv( io.StringIO(data_string), sep="\t", encoding='utf-8')
print(df)
```

**Output**: `.\SO\67060643.py`

```
                                                Text Sentimen
0   la la la...hm hmm  "Semua diam ,semua bisu"...  Positif
1                Cerita silat lae  semacam wejangan  Negatif
2                        sewot.. dukung dia terus  Positif
3                           kunyuk!!!! kuy gaslah  Negatif
4  aku sudah mengalaminya  tetiba muncul grub wa  Negatif
5                                g lagi bosan huft   Negatif
```

Comment: What if there are 200 comments? Do we have to manually rewrite all comment texts?